# Loop though a filtered list

Tags: excel

i have a list of invoices numbers on a spreadsheet that needs cross checking against another workbook and to enter the date of payment on to the second workbook,

Book one

| invoiceID | paid on. |
| --- | --- |
| 234. | 23/3/23 |
| 764. |  |

Book two

| invoiceID | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 234. | paid. |
| 764. | outstanding |

There are over 100 ID numbers how do I loop through the ID numbers and cross check them on the other workbook

If I Dim the range of the ID column . Is there a way I can set the criteria to search each entry

Comment: there are dozens of ways to do this.  simplest and quickest would probably be the XLOOKUP function if you have it in your version, or a VLOOKUP wrapped in an IF formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a VLOOKUP function to check whether there is a number for that ID in book one and nest this in an IF function. If there is a number (e.g. a date) then it will return 'paid' but if it is blank or there is something else (e.g. text) then it will return 'outstanding'.

There are other options but this works and is straightforward. This is for cell B2 in book two and you can drag it down to all of the ID numbers:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A2,[Book1]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)),"paid","outstanding")
```